# Copy Edittext value to onther Edittext in the same Fragment with a button click

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

i have a tab fragment called addvalue.fragment

```
   public class addvalue extends Fragment { 
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_add,
                    container, false);
}
```

and the xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/copy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Valider"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

i want the copy to content of EditText1 to EditText2 woth the button click how can i do that in fragment

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container, false);
        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.copy);
        final EditText et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        final EditText et2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EditText2);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // copy from edittext1 to edittext2
                et1.setText(et2.getText());
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm not sure that this is what you want.

Comment: You missed the part: **with the button click**

Comment: @Prerak Sola, I fixed it.